# full-text-search on Win SBS 2008 network drive using Win 7 64-bit client

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, full-text-search

I got a **Win SBS 2008** that servers 10 Client machines. 2 of the 10 client machines are running **Win 7 64-bit**. The other 8 are running **Win XP 32-bit**. The **Win SBS 2008** has a folder which contains bills that the company has written for its customers. The folder is a **shared network drive**. All 8 **Win XP 32-bit** clients have the **Windows search plugin** installed ([Windows Search plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23)), enabling a *full-text-search within pdf-files located on that shared network drive*.

However, after searching the web I couldn't find a **pure Windows solution** for the **Win 7 64-bit** clients to achieve aforementioned searching solution in the same fashion as with the **Win XP 32-bit** clients.

There seem to be solutions which involve 3rd party programs. If there is no pure windows solution to this problem, please name a **third party software** for which the *following statements are positive*:

1. open source
2. do full text search in pdf-files located on a shared network drive
3. do so under Win 7 64-bit

If the description does not suffice for a solution outline. Please let me know which informations are lacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find plugin for win7 because "search" is already embedded in it, no additional installation needed.
Just make sure you have index of required drive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search

Answer (score 0):

For the last couple of years I have used the [NeoSearch](https://www.koshyjohn.com/software/neosearch/) Utility Tool.

It reads from Network Drives and is easily configurable.